# How to deduce this equality based on the fact that these two terms must be the same?

Tags: coq, equality, pattern-matching

Brief (but possibly inaccurate) Summary:

I have a proposition `H : Prop1 p q`. When I use `inversion` on the proposition, I get something like `t1 : tree p` and `t2 : tree q`. However, when I have `Prop1 p p`, I cannot get Coq to realize that `t1 = t2`.

[Gist link to proof script](https://gist.github.com/Agnishom/adcb9072fe71db31878a092a7a85b6eb)

---

I have a definition of a `SimpleRegex` with characters and concatenation. They are defined as follows:

```ml
Inductive SimpleRegex : Type :=
| CharClass : (A -> bool) -> SimpleRegex
| Concat : SimpleRegex -> SimpleRegex -> SimpleRegex
.

Inductive parse_tree : SimpleRegex -> list A -> Type :=
| parse_charclass : forall f x,
    f x = true ->
    parse_tree (CharClass f) [x]
| parse_concat : forall r1 r2 s1 s2,
    parse_tree r1 s1 ->
    parse_tree r2 s2 ->
    parse_tree (Concat r1 r2) (s1 ++ s2)
.
```

I want to define a `prefer` relation that sets up a lexicographic order.

```ml
Inductive prefer : forall (r : SimpleRegex) (w1 w2 : list A),
    parse_tree r w1 -> parse_tree r w2 -> Prop :=
| prefer_concat_lex1 :
    forall (r s : SimpleRegex) (wr1 wr2 ws1 ws2 : list A)
    (pwr1 : parse_tree r wr1) (pwr2 : parse_tree r wr2)
    (pws1 : parse_tree s ws1) (pws2 : parse_tree s ws2),
    prefer r wr1 wr2 pwr1 pwr2 
    -> prefer (Concat r s) (wr1 ++ ws1) (wr2 ++ ws2) 
        (parse_concat r s wr1 ws1 pwr1 pws1) (parse_concat r s wr2 ws2 pwr2 pws2)
| prefer_concat_lex2 :
    forall (r s : SimpleRegex) (wr ws1 ws2 : list A)
    (pwr : parse_tree r wr)
    (pws1 : parse_tree s ws1) (pws2 : parse_tree s ws2),
    prefer s ws1 ws2 pws1 pws2
    -> prefer (Concat r s) (wr ++ ws1) (wr ++ ws2)
        (parse_concat r s wr ws1 pwr pws1) (parse_concat r s wr ws2 pwr pws2)
.
```

A plain english description of the two rules are (roughly) as follows:

1. Suppose `r` and `s` are SimpleRegexes, and `wr1, wr2 ∈〖r〗` and `ws1, ws2 ∈〖s〗`. If we prefer a parse tree `prw1` witnessing `wr1 ∈〖r〗` more than `prw2` witnessing `wr2 ∈〖r〗`, then `parse_concat prw1 psw1` is preferred to `parse_concat prw2 psw2` as parse trees.
2. Suppose `r` and `s` are SimpleRegexes, and `ws1, ws2 ∈〖s〗`. Then, for any `wr ∈〖r〗`, with parse tree `pwr`, the parse tree `parse_concat pwr psw1` is preferred to `parse_concat pwr psw2` as parse trees.

I want to prove the following Proposition

```
Lemma prefer_antirefl : forall r w (p : parse_tree r w),
    ~ prefer r w w p p.
```

It is easy to get started.

```ml
Lemma prefer_charclass_antirefl :
    forall (c : A -> bool) (w : list A) (p : parse_tree (CharClass c) w),
    ~ prefer (CharClass c) w w p p.
Proof.
    unfold not. intros.
    remember (CharClass c) as r.
    destruct p; inversion Heqr.
    - inversion H.
Qed.

Lemma prefer_antirefl : forall r w (p : parse_tree r w),
    ~ prefer r w w p p.
Proof.
    unfold not. induction r; intros.
    - now apply prefer_charclass_antirefl in H.
    - remember (Concat r1 r2) as r.
      destruct p; inversion Heqr.
      (* This inversion above does away with all the cases 
         where p is not related to Concat
      *)
      inversion H. subst.
      + admit.
      + admit.
Admitted.
```

At the point of the first admit, I have the following:

```
A: Type
r1, r2: SimpleRegex
IHr1: forall (w : list A) (p : parse_tree r1 w), prefer r1 w w p p -> False
IHr2: forall (w : list A) (p : parse_tree r2 w), prefer r2 w w p p -> False
Heqr: Concat r1 r2 = Concat r1 r2
s1, s2: list A
p1: parse_tree r1 s1
p2: parse_tree r2 s2
H: prefer (Concat r1 r2) (s1 ++ s2) (s1 ++ s2)
      (parse_concat r1 r2 s1 s2 p1 p2) (parse_concat r1 r2 s1 s2 p1 p2)
pwr3, pwr0: parse_tree r1 s1
H3: prefer r1 s1 s1 pwr0 pwr3
H5, H6, H7: s1 ++ s2 = s1 ++ s2
pws0: parse_tree r2 s2
```

Unfortunately, Coq does not realize that pwr3 and pwr0 must be the same tree since they came from the same `parse_concat` tree in H.

How do I inform Coq of this, and close the proof?

[Gist Available Here](https://gist.github.com/Agnishom/adcb9072fe71db31878a092a7a85b6eb) (RegexParseTreesSimple.v)

---

Edit: I thought I should edit to clarify the question I am asking, and answer some of the questions in the comments.

**Question 1**:

I have the following hypothesis `H`

```
H: prefer (Concat r1 r2) (s1 ++ s2) (s1 ++ s2)
      (parse_concat r1 r2 s1 s2 p1 p2) (parse_concat r1 r2 s1 s2 p1 p2)
```

where `s1, s2` are the strings, `p1, p2` are the parse trees.

Notice that the last two arguments of `H` are *syntactically* the same. Since the rule `prefer_concat_lex1` to construct `H`, applying inversion on `H` should give us `p1, p2` back and a proposition `prefer r1 s1 s1 p1 p1`. Unfortunately, instead of finding `p1` and `p2` by pattern matching the `parse_concat`s, Coq comes up with two new `pwr3, pwr0`, of which we know nothing.

How do I get Coq to give us the hypothesis `prefer r1 s1 s1 p1 p1`?

**Question 2:** If this is impossible, how do I prove `prefer_antirefl` as stated above?

**Clarification:** User Lolo says

> Your definition of prefer seems strange there is no base case.

Indeed that is true. In my [full version](https://gist.github.com/Agnishom/adcb9072fe71db31878a092a7a85b6eb#file-regexparsetreesfull-v), I do have a base case, but I have tried to find a minimal complete example for the purpose of this example to replicate the issue.

Comment: Have you tried proving a lemma saying that two parse trees over the same regular expession and list are equal?

Comment: Your definition of `prefer` seems strange there is no base case.

Comment: @Lolo I presented a simpler version of my setup so that it is just large enough to represent the main problem I am stuck with

Comment: @AndrejBauer I do not want to rely on such a lemma. I think what I want in this case should be possible anyway, because the last two arguments of `prefer` in `H` are syntactically the same thing.

Comment: It's not possible. You should try proving the lemma, you'll discover that there is more to it than you think. For instance, if you have `parse_charclass f x p` and `pase_charclass f x q` where `p : f x = true` and `q : f x = true`, why do you think it follows `p = q`?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I am not really sure whether two `Prop`s which are proofs of the same thing are equal or not. I don't think they should be. Similarly, I do not think that two parse trees for the given regular expression and word pair are necessarily equal. I am not really sure this applies to the "inversion of H". However, I have added some more details (as an edit) to my question above. In case I am misguided with question 1, I still think it should be possible to answer question 2

Comment: I took a look at your gist. It looks like `inversion` just isn't smart enough, and you'll have to break things down. Can't you separately prove `prefer_concat_antirefl` (similarly to `prefer_union_antirefl`) and any other auxiliary lemma needed?

Comment: I left a comment on your gist.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I don't think I know how to prove `prefer_concat_antirefl` seperately either. I think the same issues would show up.

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay: I am at this point bothered by how you implemented parsing. Why are you using `nth_error`, rather than a more structured definition (such as the one I suggested in the gist comments)?

Comment: @AndrejBauer thank you, your suggestion makes sense. but I don't think it is really relevant to the problem I am having. You can simply look at RegexParseTreesSimple.v and replicate the issue. (and ignore the other file)

Answer (score 2):

This is a dependent inversion problem that has been bothering many Coq users. There is a short answer on Stack Overflow [1].

For your example, we have `H` before inversion:

```ml
H : prefer (Concat r0 r3) (app s1 s2) (app s1 s2) (parse_concat r0 r3 s1 s2 p1 p2)
      (parse_concat r0 r3 s1 s2 p1 p2)
```

After `inversion H`, we have `pwr0, pwr3 : parse_tree r0 s1`.
We know they both come from `p1`, so they should be equal.
But actually they are linked to `p1` as

```ml
H10 : existT (fun r1 : SimpleRegex => {s1 : list A & parse_tree r1 s1}) r0
        (existT (fun s1 : list A => parse_tree r0 s1) s1 pwr0) =
      existT (fun r1 : SimpleRegex => {s1 : list A & parse_tree r1 s1}) r0
        (existT (fun s1 : list A => parse_tree r0 s1) s1 p1)
H15 : existT (fun r1 : SimpleRegex => {s1 : list A & parse_tree r1 s1}) r0
        (existT (fun s1 : list A => parse_tree r0 s1) s1 pwr3) =
      existT (fun r1 : SimpleRegex => {s1 : list A & parse_tree r1 s1}) r0
        (existT (fun s1 : list A => parse_tree r0 s1) s1 p1)
```

Coq's type system does not allow us to directly derive `pwr0 = p1` and `pwr3 = p1`.
I don't know why it is not allowed, but I find we can only derive from `existT P x a = existT P x b` to `eq_rect x P a x H = b` (an induced version of `a` equals `b`, instead of `a` itself), but not `a = b`, using `inversion_sigma` [2].

```ml
Require Import Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.

Context (A : Type) (P : A -> Type) (x : A).

Goal forall a b : P x,
  existT P x a = existT P x b -> a = b.
Proof.
  intros. inversion_sigma H.
```

If we can prove `H = @eq_refl A x` (axiom K [3]), then `eq_rect x P a x H` evaluates to `a`:

```ml
  assert (H = eq_refl) by admit.
  subst H.
  simpl in H0.
  apply H0.
```

If equality of `SimpleRegex` is decidable, which should be the case, you can use `inj_pair2_eq_dec` [1] to resolve your problem. Otherwise, you might want to accept axiom K.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720137/inversion-produces-unexpected-existt-in-coq

[2] https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacn.inversion_sigma

[3] https://coq.inria.fr/files/adt-2fev10-corbineau.pdf

Comment: This seems to be more involved than I thought it was :(

Comment: Is there some reason decidability is needed? I like my regexes to have predicates of the form `(A -> bool)` in the form of atomic characters, making equality undecidable